# @throw NSException vs NSException raise

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, throw, raise

What is the difference between `@throw NSException` and `NSException raise`? I wonder which one I should rather use (there is a proper use case to use one) and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Apple docs,

> An important difference between `@throw` and `raise` is that the latter can be sent only to an `NSException object` whereas `@throw` can take other types of objects as its argument (such as string objects). Cocoa applications should @throw only `NSException objects`.
>
> Typically you throw or raise an exception inside an exception-handling domain, which is a block of code marked off by the @try compiler directive.
>
> See “[Handling Exceptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html)” for details.
>
> Within exception handling domains you can re-propagate exceptions caught by local exception handlers to higher-level handlers either by sending the NSException object another raise message or by using it with another @throw directive.

For further details you can refer the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html).